# Are there any good tutorials for learning AS3 with FlashDevelop?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087632/flashdevelop-training-materials-tutorials-books-flex-flash-development-witho) question, and it mentions the FlashDevelop wiki. However, I couldn't find anything there at all.

Where is a good place to start? I have done some work with MXML projects using the Flex SDK, but never any ActionScript programming.

Comment: Are you asking how to use FlashDevelop or how to program in AS3?  They're really different questions.  Which IDE you use doesn't have all that much bearing on how you develop and there are several IDE's that support AS3.  If you want to learn AS3, just look for AS3 tutorials and follow along regardless of what IDE they mention (but they probably wouldn't mention any).

Comment: @Sam: Okay... where would be a good place for AS3 tutorials? I'm sure someone somewhere has asked __that__ question somewhere on SO before.

Comment: Here's 1 million+ links for you.  http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=as3+tutorials

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a [tutorial to get Flash Develop up and running and a quick primer into actionscript](http://prototyprally.com/making-games-in-actionscript-3-using-flashdevelop-part-1-the-setup/) on my blog.

Sorry for the shameless self promotion, but I figured it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The official Adobe site has a nice [Getting Started guide](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/getting_started.html) for AS3 together with some [sample code](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/as3.html). Getting **Programming ActionScript 3.0** or the complete **Complete Flex 3 Documentation** @ the official [Flex docs site](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/) should be very useful too.

Apart from the official docs, I found this [tutorial](http://flashpunk.net/forums/index.php?topic=22.0) quite useful while doing a small project with Flashdevelop + AS3. It's not complete but does get you started.

Hope this helps.